# Can you use any other expressions in the WHEN condition for a task in snowflake besides SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want a task only to run when a condition is met, i.e. like when a specific record appears in another table. Can I write a SQL expression that will evaluate to True when that record appears and place it in the WHEN clause for a task?

Currently trying to do something like this but keep receiving the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnceD.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is currently limited to SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA.

[CREATE TASK - Optional Parameters](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#optional-parameters)

> ```
> WHEN <boolean_expr>
> ```
>
> Currently, **only** the following function is supported for evaluation in the SQL expression:
>
> ```
> SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA
> ```